# Как сделать проверку того, выдал ли пользователь приложению рут доступ?

Tags: java, android, root

Делаю приложение с необходимостью рут доступа. Как мне можно сделать проверку того разрешил ли пользователь рут доступ моему приложению, или нет?

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой и базовый пример определения root:

```
/**
   * Checks if the device is rooted.
   *
   * @return <code>true</code> if the device is rooted, <code>false</code> otherwise.
   */
  public static boolean isRooted() {

    // get from build info
    String buildTags = android.os.Build.TAGS;
    if (buildTags != null && buildTags.contains("test-keys")) {
      return true;
    }

    // check if /system/app/Superuser.apk is present
    try {
      File file = new File("/system/app/Superuser.apk");
      if (file.exists()) {
        return true;
      }
    } catch (Exception e1) {
      // ignore
    }

    // try executing commands
    return canExecuteCommand("/system/xbin/which su")
        || canExecuteCommand("/system/bin/which su") || canExecuteCommand("which su");
  }

  // executes a command on the system
  private static boolean canExecuteCommand(String command) {
    boolean executedSuccesfully;
    try {
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
      executedSuccesfully = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      executedSuccesfully = false;
    }

    return executedSuccesfully;
  }
```

Для более продвинутого определения root-a посмотрите [Android Root Beer](https://github.com/scottyab/rootbeer).

Answer (score 0):

думаю на английской части SO можно найти ответ. зависит от способа получения рута на устройстве. если есть su, то можно попробовать открыть файл/директорию за пределами каталога приложения. вот пример для изменения прав доступа (в моем случае для компорта) на Android-x86. но может он с косяками и надо доотладить.

```
static public boolean fixAndroidDeviceAccess(String path) {
    File device = new File(path);
    /* Check access permission */
    if (!device.canRead() || !device.canWrite()) {
        try {
            /* Missing read/write permission, trying to chmod the file */
            Process su;
            su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/su");
            String cmd = "chmod +rw " + device.getAbsolutePath() + "\n"
                    + "exit\n";
            su.getOutputStream().write(cmd.getBytes());
            if (su.waitFor() != 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
            return false;
        }
    }
    return device.canRead() && device.canWrite();
}
```